# Why Maven wants to download ALL my dependecies from ALL my repostories?

Tags: maven, repository, jackson

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xsi:schemaLocation=
 "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
 xmlns=
 "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.pw</groupId>
 <artifactId>pocketwaitress-android</artifactId>
 <name>PocketWaitress Android</name>
 <packaging>apk</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 <repositories>         
      <repository>
           <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
           <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
           <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
           <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
      </repository><!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
      <repository>
           <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
           <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
           <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
           <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
      </repository>
    <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
    </repository>

 </repositories>
 <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
           <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.3.2</version>
           <configuration>
                <sdk>
                     <platform>7</platform>
                     <path>D:/WorkFolder/Android-SDK2</path>
                </sdk>
                <emulator>
                     <avd>WVGA-2.1</avd>
                </emulator>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
           </plugin>
      </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
           <artifactId>android</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>com.pw</groupId>
           <artifactId>model</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehouse.jackson</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehouse.jackson</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.9</version>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

The latest addons to this are the Jackson dependecies.

The output of deploy is:

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building PocketWaitress Android 1.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehouse/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.9/jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.codehouse.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9 is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehouse/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.9/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.codehouse.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9 is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehouse/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.9/jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
    Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehouse/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.9/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Skipping PocketWaitress Android
    [INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.313s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 12 12:50:48 CEST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/174M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pocketwaitress-android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.pw:pocketwaitress-android:apk:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehouse.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9, org.codehouse.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9: Failure to find org.codehouse.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9 in http://maven.springframework.org/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.milestone has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Apparently maven manages to download the jackson dependecies, from the central maven repository but then it tries to download them from http://maven.springframework.org/milestone too! 
Why is that? Do i need to define somehow which dependencies are fetched from which repo? Makes no sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jackson dependencies are not downloaded. When download is successful you will see something like
`Downloaded: xy`
Recheck your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen funky errors like this before and I usually do two things:

First, make sure your internet connection is working correctly - if Maven cannot connect to a particular repository, it will search additional repositories for the artifact and can potentially give misleading error messages (such as appearing to search the wrong repo).

Next, run your build again with the `-U` flag to force updates.

Again, not certain this is the problem, but I've seen similar behavior fixed by the above steps.  Might be worth a shot.